# Customising Jenkins' appearance to make it easier to tell instances apart

Tags: jenkins

I am responsible for four different Jenkins installations - two test and two production servers.

What options do I have from within Jenkins to make it more obvious which machine I am connected to?

What I would like to do is be able to change the Jenkins text at the top of the screen to 'Jenkins Department 1 Test' - is this possible? Are there other options such as changing colours etc?

Comment: You can use one jenkins installation to drive multiple slaves. Then, identifying the server won't be an issue.

Comment: I have a test and prod instance... upgrades and plugin development happen in test, so I have a need to tell them apart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is with the [Simple Theme Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin).

> A plugin for Jenkins that supports custom CSS & JavaScript.

You can make your own simple css and/or javascript, point to the file in the configuration and you're done. Or you can use existing css from the internet.

Answer (score 6):

### obsolete as of 2017

Try the [Page Markup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Page+Markup+Plugin).

> Adds custom HTML content to header & footer on all Hudson pages.
>   Use this plugin to add your own custom content (e.g. CSS, site headers, and site footers) to Hudson pages.

I haven't used this plugin myself, but you should be able to override the default CSS styles to insert your own header text or image.

Alternatively, you can edit the CSS / images yourself in `JENKINS_HOME/war/css` and `JENKINS_HOME/war/images`, but I don't recommend that since you'll probably lose any customizations when you upgrade.

Comment: It looks like the `Page Markup Plugin` was discontinued. The original Wiki page is at this moment 6 years old :-(

Comment: `No information for the plugin 'page-markup' is available. It may have been removed from distribution.`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use tools like Greasemonkey (Firefox) or a similar built in ability with in Chrome (http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) to have JavaScript code alter the appearance of the page. You'd get a lot of flexibility and could potentially go so far as to prohibit certain commands from executing or enforce additional restrictions when executing certain commands on the production servers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to or instead of the `Simple Theme Plugin` proposed by @Illidanek, you might also try the [jQuery Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/jQuery+Plugin).

> This plugin is a library plugin for other plugins to share common jQuery. It also allows users to use jQuery on each view descriptions.

It doesn't completely match your requirements, but it might be useful to add jQuery snippets for special formatting/styling/html-manipulation in the Jenkins "System Message", in view descriptions or in job descriptions.

I personally often prefer the `Simple Theme Plugin`.