# How do I customize Jenkins theme?

Tags: jenkins, themes, customization, appearance

I want to change background images, logo ,headings and add some buttons.
I have the following UI related plugins installed

1) Simple Theme Plugin
A plugin for Jenkins that supports custom CSS & JavaScript. You can customize Jenkins's appearance (ex. his gentle face on the background).
version 0.3

2) UI Themes: Plugin
This plugin provides UI themes for Jenkins.
version 2.1.1

I have found some answer regarding the same but didn't find much help.

-->> [Customising Jenkins' appearance to make it easier to tell instances apart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037372/customising-jenkins-appearance-to-make-it-easier-to-tell-instances-apart)

-->> http://isotope11.com/blog/styling-your-jenkins-continuous-integration-server

Please give steps or any links from which I can completely change the appearance of my Jenkins server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with CSS styling, you could create a theme, by making a CSS styling file and uploading it to a directly-serving server (*Even the one your using for jenkins, in a new folder*) or JavaScript styling (*same diddy*) could be added to the option at your jenkins {host}/configure under "Theme". However, in my experience the 1.609.1 version of jenkins does NOT support this plugin properly in OpenShift Cloud hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of full theme in progress in [`jenkinsci/dark-theme`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/dark-theme).

It is not yet ready, but can illustrate how the CSS is setup with a Jenkins 2.220+ (May 2020)

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/dark-theme/master/docs/images/screenshot_build_console.PNG]

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable in CSS, you can easily customize logo and title in theme with `.css` file.
For example, I have added `JENKINS_HOME/usercontent/mytheme.css` file `JENKINS_HOME/usercontent/logo.png` as my logo and follow the css below:

```css
@charset “utf-8”;
#header .logo {
  height: 36px;
}


/* Custom style for my Jenkins Platform */

.logo {
  background: url(/userContent/logo.png) no-repeat 10px center;
}

.logo img {
  display: none;
}

.logo:after {
  content: 'Jenkins my instance';
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
} // Content after logo
```

Just check in Configure System --> Theme you must give CSS path of above `mytheme.css` file. & Refresh your Jenkins Page.

See the reference [LINK](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/how-to-apply-custom-styling-to-my-instance) here !