# HTML pages of Jenkins

Tags: html, css, jenkins

I'm working with jenkins for a while now and i'm thinking of building my own layout with jenkins .. I know there is a plugin that allows you to make your own css file.

But i was thinking further than that i'm more looking to change names of html attributes aswell and just use the Jenkins pages. Does anybody know where i can find the HTML pages of Jenkins to change it to my wanted code.

I already searched in the local folders of jenkins but couldn't find anything.

Kind regards

Dimitri

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins application is deployed with Tomcat (for example), all css files are in the webapps/ROOT/css folder:

[image]

The js files are in the webapps/ROOT/scripts folder:

[image]

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Oke,But i'm not looking for the CSS files but really for the html pages as you can see when you click on jenkins and look at the page source .. That are the ones i'm looking for

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think that the HTML pages are generated from the css and the js files. If you want to customise the Jenkins layout, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037372/customising-jenkins-appearance-to-make-it-easier-to-tell-instances-apart

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins are shipped with a `.war` package. To change or customize jenkins html or css in order to change its looking, you need to change the source code or jenkins, that means you probably should be a jenkins developer. And a good thing for you is jenkins is a open source software, you can always get its code from [Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/9c443c8d5bafd63fce574f6d0cf400cd8fe1f124/war/src/main/webapp)

And I think [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/9c443c8d5bafd63fce574f6d0cf400cd8fe1f124/war/src/main/webapp) is what you are looking for, it includes the css/html of jenkins. Just a reminder, after you change the css/html of it, you should repackage it to the `.war` format before you can use it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, What i'm looking to do is to create a own HTML/css website including different tools like jenkins so we have our own layout and website that we can later implement in our company. So a fully own build jenkins with the javascripts behind it thats my idea .. Do you guys think thats possible to do or not ?

Comment: Is there no other way than code changes because i can't find any HTML code inside all folders .. I'm not a javascript developper. So i'm more looking for a gui to change the layout to the layout we want and save it again .. I know HTML code so thats no problem